# How to convert text to Base58 on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, decode, encode

I want to convert a message like "Hello World" to base58 and then been able to decode it using node.js.[Base-58 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-58) has the below explanation but I can't exactly understand how to convert my message.

```
Base58.encode(a Buffer or Uint8Array) returns a String
Base58.decode(a String) returns a Buffer
```

I guess that I need to convert the message first to something else and then to base58.And to decode the base58 message, again, a conversion to something else is needed and from there to text, right?

Comment: Have you read up on [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)? That should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var codedString = Base58.encode(new Buffer("Hello world"));
```

You will get it

Comment: Where is Base58 coming from? Node 20 says it's not defined

Answer (score 5):

To encode:

```
var message = "Hello World";
var codedString = Base58.encode(new Buffer(message));
console.log (codedString);
```

This encoded the message successfully

```
JxF12TrwUP45BMd
```

Then, to decode:

```
var decodedString = Base58.decode(codedString);
var buff = new Buffer(decodedString);
console.log(buff.toString('utf8'));
```

This decoded the message successfully

```
Hello World
```